# My name no longer appears on gnome-panel

Tags: gnome, indicator, username

I booted up my laptop this morning to find my name no longer appears beside the power off button in the top right hand corner of the top gnome panel:

[image]

I tried deleting and re-adding the indicator applet session to the panel but it still doesn't display my name.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have the package `indicator-me` installed?

Comment: No I don't, is that's what's missing?

Comment: Yes, it is. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install the `indicator-me` package.

Comment: Ah thanks, it was installed, but I uninstalled gwibber last night and didn't realise one of it's dependancies was indicator-me. Thanks!